# Se cierra aplicación de android studio al ejecutarla en celular

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app

Para mis primeras practicas de la escuela estamos haciendo aplicaciones en android studio utilizando Java, realmente las aplicaciones son demasiado basicas ya que solo se tratan de que cuando se presione un boton haga tal cosa. Pero mi problema viene que cuando quiero ejecutar mi app en mi celular (Conecto mi celular por usb a la laptop y desde el IDE de android studio lo seleccionó y le doy en Run) se instala la app e inmediatamente se cierra completamente. He dado un vistaso por la terminal del IDE al momento de ejecutar mi app y me muestra este siguiente error, no creo que se trata con algo relacionado al codigo de la app, ya que estoy casi seguro que esta bien, sin errores.

Este es el error que me da:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sumabasica, PID: 24306
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sumabasica/com.example.sumabasica.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3052)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:159)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:675)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:848)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
        at com.example.sumabasica.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:12)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3040)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24306 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:52492', transport: 'socket'
```

Esta es la parte de mi código del MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sumabasica;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String pers[] = {"40000000", "17000000", "6500000", "10000000", "30000000", "14000000", "183000000", "44000000", "31000000", "3500000"};

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                tv.setText(pers[position]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Y esta es la parte del activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="379dp"
        android:layout_height="562dp"
        android:entries="@array/paises"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Así es como luce el diseño
[image: Diseño de la app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se describe aquì:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo
> android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object
> reference

Me parece que el problema es que tratas de obtener las referencias de estos elementos pero no hay un contexto para usar `findViewById()` :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
```

Debes obtener las referencias de las vistas dentro de `onCreate()` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
       ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);


        String pers[] = {"40000000", "17000000", "6500000", "10000000", "30000000", "14000000", "183000000", "44000000", "31000000", "3500000"};

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                tv.setText(pers[position]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si era éso, cambié esas instancias dentro del onCreate y se solucionó.

Comment: Si, lo que sucede es que fuera de onCreate() no puede obtener el contexto para llamar findViewById(), saludos.